# AWS Athena : run Athena using Lambda does not save in S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-athena

I am using Athena using lambda, and just noticed that result of query execution is success but there is nothing in S3 bucket. S3 bucket is public and has permission to put objects, so I can't find any problem with S3 bucket. I wonder if there is solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Providing S3 write permission to lambda execution role may help.